How to dynamic the suffixes on dates (1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th etc) in excel
Is there any way to get the suffixes on dates.
"A" column contains date and I need the required format in "B" column as mentioned below
A1: 6/1/2024    B1: 01st Jun 2024
A2: 6/9/2024    B2: 09th Jun 2024
A3: 6/22/2024   B3: 22nd Jun 2024.
As per my knowledge I can do it by taking helper column & I can do Vlookup. Is there any other method to do the same??
Thank you

Why do you need that? I am just curious. It makes reading the dates harder.

I won't add as an answer as you've already got one, but I usually go to Ordinal Suffixes In Excel (RIP) for the =A1&IF(AND(MOD(ABS(A1),100)>=10,MOD(ABS(A1),100)<=14),"th",         CHOOSE(MOD(ABS(A1),10)+1,"th","st","nd","rd","th","th","th","th","th","th")).  Also a VBA solution on the same page.

@virolino May not be the reason the OP wants it for, but I use it sometimes for report headings.  "Report for 14th June" reads better than "Report for 14 June" in my opinion.

@virolino We used this format for Week Commencing. :-)

Here is an alternative method using dynamic array formulas:


• Formula used in cell E1
=MAP(D1#,LAMBDA(α,
  LET(δ,DAY(α),
  δ&CHOOSE(IF(SUM(--(δ={11,12,13})),4,MIN(MOD(δ-1,10)+1,4)),"st","nd","rd","th")&
  TEXT(α," mmm e"))))



According to this source there are some exception with days 1,2,3,21,22,23 and 31 so I've been testing with July because it got 31 days.

The formula with no leading 0 would be:
=DAY(A1)&IF(SUM(--(DAY(A1)={1;2;3;21;22;23;31}))>0;CHOOSE(RIGHT(DAY(A1);1);"st";"nd";"rd");"th")&" "&TEXT(A1;"mmm yyyy")

Notice my argument separator is ; so you may need to replace those with commas due to Excel setup.
Also, the part TEXT(A1;"mmm yyyy") needs to be adapted to your regional settings. In my case, I got spanish excel so it would be TEXT(A1;"mmm aaaa")
In case you want to force the leading 0 (even if it's not right) just add an extra RIGHT formula:
=RIGHT("0"& whole_original_formula; 13)

Thanks @virolino and @RonRosefeld for pointing me in the right direction!

I think you need to update the formula: "22th" ? Is that "twenty twoth" or twenty teeth"? :) It looks quite like a panel I saw in an airport, mentioning the "1nd floor"...

Also, the leading zeros are far from customary in ordinal numbers (IMO, non-native English xpeaker).

You might want to try your formula with 11, 12, 13 - they are exceptions and use "th", not st, nd, rd...

@virolino I've added the leading zero just because OP posted like that. About 11, 12 and 13, formula works perfectly due to this part IF(DAY(A1)>3;"th"

I verified, you are right. But it fails for 21, 22, 23 and 31 (which get "th" also) :) And please remove that leading zero, most likely OP made a mistake. Most people here are not English speakers - this is why dates are sometimes confusing.

@FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns In English, it would properly be 21st, 22nd, 23rd and 31st

@virolino I see your point. You were not right with 11, 12 and 13 buy you are absolutely right about 21,22,23 and 31 :). Let me fix that

@virolino Now it's fixed properly. Thanks for your help!

Assuming your date is in A2.
Also assuming your date is actually a date, and not text.
You can get the day, month and year like this (e.g., 06/15/2024)
Day:     B2 = TEXT(A2, "dd")        // returns "15" (text)
Month:   C2 = TEXT(A2, "mmm")       // returns "Jun"
Year:    D2 = TEXT(A2, "yyyy")      // returns "2024"
Day_num: E2 = VALUE(TEXT(A2, "dd")) // returns 15 (number)

Now to add the ordinal suffixes you take in the Day (B2) and pick the right suffix, using this formula:
=B2&IF(AND(E2>10,E2<20),"th",CHOOSE(MOD(B2,10)+1,"th","st","nd","rd","th","th","th","th","th","th" ))

This takes into account that 11, 12, 13 don't have "st", "nd" and "rd", but all "th" (unlike 1, 2, 3 and 21, 22, 23).
To do it all in one step:
=TEXT(A2, "dd")&IF(AND(VALUE(TEXT(A2, "dd"))>10,VALUE(TEXT(A2, "dd"))<20),"th",CHOOSE(MOD(TEXT(A2, "dd"),10)+1,"th","st","nd","rd","th","th","th","th","th","th" ))&" "&TEXT(A2, "mmm")&" "&TEXT(A2, "yyyy")


Thank you for your response, I tried this one but formula little lengthy.
=IF(OR(DAY(B5)={1,21,31}),TEXT(B5,"dd")&"st",IF(OR(DAY(B5)={2,22}),TEXT(B5,"dd")&"nd",IF(OR(DAY(B5)={3,23}),TEXT(B5,"dd")&"rd",TEXT(B5,"dd")&"th")))

Leading 0 looks good...

@Manoj, if you're afraid of long formulas then Excel may not be the right tool for you.

Tested this, but 11th, 12th and 13th fail... 11st, 12nd and 13rd are the results of your formula.

Ah, damn you're right @Solar Mike. Fixing it right now.

Multiply the function in B2 by 1 to turn text into a number then your if() will work as expected. quickest solution, so for the one step solution TEXT(A2, "dd")*1 and has the benefit of loosing the leading 0

I added another helper column that has day as number to use in the comparison <>.

@Solar Mike, the leading zero was actually a requirement here if you look at the question (I don't like it either).

So you prefer an extra column instead of just multiplying by 1?

The columns are just there to better understand how the formula works. The last formula does it all in one step.

Plus, I know that multipying by one turns text into value, but I don't like that it's not explicit. It's a weird quirk how Excel makes this implicit type conversion. Explicit >> Implicit. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zen_of_Python

@Sebastian People may think greater than me, I feel the formula looks lengthy then I will seek help from others like you. :-)
